# Generate all passwords that meet the criteria

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to create a program that will generate all passwords which contain 2 lower case letters, 2 digits and 3 uppercase letters. I've been trying to do it initially in Java by using Streams. When I saw I was getting nowhere I decided to do it in Python (where I don't really have any knowledge since I just started using it)
Initially I thought that I will use itertools.combinations and 3 lists where I have all digits, uppercase letters and lowercase letters but I am running out of memory (with 32GB or RAM). Then I've tried getting a list of all combinations for digits, lower case letters and uppercase letters each in its own variable. Now I don't know how would I be able to put that together.

This is what I currently have

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase

digits = '1234567890'
lowLetters = ascii_lowercase
upLetters = ascii_uppercase

digitComb = combinations_with_replacement(digits, 2)
upLettersComb = combinations_with_replacement(upLetters, 2)
lowLettersComb = combinations_with_replacement(lowLetters, 3)
fullList = digitComb + upLettersComb + lowLettersComb
```

I really have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how many passwords you are trying to generate? Your 32GB of memory are not enough to get them all, whatever the language.

Comment: Fair point. But what would be a good approach for this?

Comment: 26**5 * 20 permutations.  All passwords might not be an option.  Focus the question a bit and someone can likely help.

Comment: The thing is that I need all of the combinations. Preferably stored in a file which I can then later run in a script for a brute force attack (not trying to do anything malicious, it's just part of my homework for one of my classes)

Comment: @StefanCiprianIuga Why do you need to pre-generate the passwords?  If you're running a script to do a brute-force attack, just have the script generate the passwords as it makes attempts.  That prevents you from having to store them.

Comment: @Jordan the reason why I want to store them in a separate file is because of efficiency since we are graded for how fast the program will be able to run

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with regular expression? If so you could generate (with some library) all possible matches of the regex :

```
^(?=.{7}$)(?=[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*).*$
```

As Nico238 said, your memory won't like it though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to create script that generates the password. Also, I will make a correction stating that I don't need to generate every possibility for each permutation of the 7. Instead it has to be done in groups.

```
from itertools import product
import string

numbers = string.digits
uppercaseList = string.ascii_uppercase
lowercaseList = string.ascii_lowercase

number_prod = product(numbers, numbers)
up_prod = product(uppercaseList, uppercaseList)
low_prod = product(lowercaseList, lowercaseList, lowercaseList)

result = product(number_prod, up_prod, low_prod)

f = open("passwords.txt", "w+")
print("Please wait")
for i in result:
    f.write(''.join(str(x) for v in i for x in v) + "\n")
f.close()
print("done")
```